# C# Is current network my domain

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, network-programming

I am building an add-on for office, in which I am to open a browser and navigate to an internal site, which is also exposed through dns, so that it can be accessed from outside the network/domain.

Now, in order to access this site, I need to know whether or not I am inside or outside the domain network. If I'm inside I need to access via internal ip otherwise through the exposed dns address.
This is where I ask the clever minds of stack overflow, if any of you know of a way to see if the network a computer is currently connected to, is indeed the network of the domain to which the computer/user belongs?

I have been looking at [Environment.UserDomainName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Domain.GetComputerDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getcomputerdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both of these could help me find the domain name, in theory (not tested, but expect it to work), but none of them helps me to find whether or not the current network is the domain network.

Any constructive feedback is very much appreciated!

**EDIT**
At some point this add-on is supposed to be sold to various customers, so I can't rely on something as simple as the IP looking in a specific way.
The solution must be something that can work regardless of the network the computer is connected to.

Comment: Just because someone is on *a* domain, that doesn't necessarily imply that they are on *the* domain that you're interested in (unless that's outside of how your system will be used)

Comment: I am completely aware of that, which is why I specifically wrote the following as part of my question:
"if the network a computer is currently connected to, is indeed the network of the domain to which the computer/user belongs?"
To clarify, I want to know if my current network connection is the same as the one for my domain network.

Comment: But what is the nature of the users who are connecting externally to this system - is there a possibility that they're currently sitting inside another organisation, using a computer that is joined to *that* organisation's domain? Would that scenario be valid?

Comment: That would indeed be a valid situation.
It can both be someone inside our organisation's network and e.g. a salesman on a visit at another organisation setting up something through this application, which must be saved in his own organisation's database; the database which holds the information for the internal site I mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your network gives computers unique names you can check the computer name by

```
Dns.GetHostName();
```

Or if your network has a specifically unique IP header (All IPs start with 10.1 or they are all on a Belkin router whose IPs start with 198.2) you can get all IP addresses using

```
IPAddress[] addr = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

UPDATE:

Something that shows my company's network is its DNS Suffix. Would this work for you?

```
 NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("  DNS suffix................................. :{0}",
                properties.DnsSuffix);
                Console.WriteLine("  DNS enabled ............................. : {0}",
                properties.IsDnsEnabled);
                Console.WriteLine("  Dynamically configured DNS .............. : {0}",
                properties.IsDynamicDnsEnabled);
            }
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from, and of course this is my fault for not specifying that at some point this add-on is supposed to be sold to various customers. So I can't rely on something as simple as the IP looking in a specific way.
I will update the question with this information.

Comment: What is your company's DNS suffix

Comment: If I am not completely mistaken our suffix is thorvalddata.com (that is what shows up when I'm connected through cable, to our network).
But in order to use this in a distributed application (not distributed as in scalability distribution), it would have to stored somewhere (not in the application), what the suffix is, in order to compare it to the current network and/or domain.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't store that value in your application?

Comment: Becuase I would rather not have to make a different version of the program, for every customer we sell it to. It must be so dynamic that it can just be sold and shipped as is.

Comment: Oh your question sounds like the only network we need to worry about is your own company's not the customers'. But this should still be fine. Just get the customer's website dynamically and compare. At this point you are asking me to write your entire program.

Comment: From my very first response to your answer:
"I see where you are coming from, and of course this is my fault for not specifying that at some point this add-on is supposed to be sold to various customers."

And no, I don't ask you to write the entire program. I am asking if anyone knows of a way to compare the currently connected network to the registered domain of the computer/user.